# jQuery Mobile height issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm having a really weird issue with some content that is being inserted with ajax within a `pageinit` event.

[image]

Here is the method:

```
    populateBusRoutesList : function() {
        var list = $('ul#bus-routes-list'), content = '';
        $.each(BuSeViCi.busRoutes, function(i, route){
            content += '<li>' +
                    '<a href="#" class="view-stops" data-number="'+ route.number+'">' +
                    '<img src="'+ route.img +'">' +
                    '<h3 class="ui-li-stops">'+ route.name +'</h3>'+
                    '</a></li>';
        });
        $(content).appendTo(list);
        list.listview('refresh');
        list.trigger('updatelayout');
    }
```

The `updatelayout` trigger has no effect in code but I just was trying to solve the weird behaviour. I've noticed that if I resize the browser, the problem get's solved.

Does anyones know why this happens?

Comment: Have you tried `list.trigger('create');`

Comment: Yes. No effect. Besides, `create` should be triggered if the widget is inserted in the page but I'm inserting content, not creating a new widget on the fly.

Comment: Your code isn't making a lot of sense.  You accumulate HTML in the `content` variable, but then you don't do anything with that variable.

Comment: If you watch carefully, I'm appending it in this line `$(content).appendTo(list);`

Comment: Is there a particular CSS attribute that isn't getting applied? It's unclear by your image provided what exactly is wrong. Should that red box extend the height of the `li`? If you remove the `listview('refresh')` does the styling look especially poor? Perhaps you might want to try executing your content fetching synchronously to see if it handles better that way.

Comment: Nope, the CSS is applied correctly as far as I know. The red box is mid covered and won't go further without resizing the window. Removing the `refresh`, the markup isn't enhanced so it won't work.

Comment: I second veeTrain -- I'm not clear as to what is wrong with the image you posted. What is the "weird behaviour" exactly?

Comment: @Todd look carefully and you'll see that the navbar is covering the middle of the list view element. The image is being covered and it shouldn't. As you may appreciate, the scroll bar (in Chrome) is at the bottom position and can't go further.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't catch the scroll bar was at it's bottom, preventing the bottom element from being completely displayed. What happens if you add an extra element, refresh the listview, remove the extra element, and refresh one more time? Not an ideal solution by far, but would be interesting to see if it works. Also, what browser/device are you trying this on?

Comment: Seems to be a bug in jQM - https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4219

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in jQM - github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4219

It should be fixed for the next release